# 'Socket connection error' when debugging PHP/JS on Aptana 3

Tags: php, javascript, aptana3

I'm having a problem debugging PHP with JS code through Aptana Studio. Although there were a few people that are having similar problems. I still couldn't figure out the solution.

**Aptana Studio Version is 3, build 3.1.3.2**

I have MAMP installed on my Mac and I was able to run (not debug) my PHP website from Aptana (I needed to change the Server to 'Use base URL: *http://localhost*' for my website to run)

**I have installed Aptana Debugger 1.7.2 and Firebug 1.10.0 on my Firefox 14.0.1**

However, when I try and debug my website, I get a window that says:

*Aptana Firefox extension launching...please wait.*

Then (after few seconds) I get the error message:

*'Launching Firefox - Internal Server' has encountered a problem.
Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again'*

I restarted my firefox but no dice.

Answer (score 5):

Remove Firebug before starting the Aptana debugger. Aptana will install both the Aptana Debugger and Firebug 1.8.3 for you.

To make sure Firebug doesn't update to 1.10, go to "Tools > Add-ons > Firebug 1.8.3 > More", and turn off automatic updates.

Comment: After I did what you described, I have Firebug 1.8.3 installed on my Firefox now (I also disabled the Automatic Updates). However, when I add a break-point in my PHP code and debug through Firefox, I don't get to control the flow (by 'Step Over' and 'Step Into'). Shouldn't I be able to control it? Or does it have to be JS code?

Comment: I only tried it for JS myself. But it seems like PHP debugging only available in the nightly builds, or by installing a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102978/aptana-3-0-4-and-php-debugging

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error when using Firebug 1.10, which is not compatible with the Aptana Debugger Firefox add-on.

What you need to do: Go to Firefox Add-ons and disable/uninstall Firebug 1.10, and instead enable Firebug 1.8 and the Aptana debugger extension instead.

Reported in JIRA here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3734?focusedCommentId=208816#comment-208816

Comment: Thank you. I'm not getting the error anymore, but my code is not being debugged (at least that's what I think...), for example, when I add breakpoint in my PHP code, it just ignores it and I can't step through the code... Also the error did not entirely disappear, I still get it sometimes!!!

Comment: This is the right idea, but [Peter Tseng](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12139883/2440976) has a better answer, as I could no longer find version 1.8 when I searched in the Firefox Add-In list. (Remove Firebug, reopen Aptana, run debug and the correct working version of Firebug will be installed.)